# SSIS writing Datetime to CSV fails

Tags: sql-server, csv, datetime, ssis, ssis-2008

I am attempting to write a Sql Server DateTime field to a CSV in SSIS and it keeps failing with:  "[Flat File Destination [742]] Error: Cannot copy or convert flat file data for column "Quotation_Date__c".

I checked the SQL using to pull the data from SQL server and it pulls the data with no errors.  Column "Quotation_Date__c" pulls data with no errors.  It's just when it attempts to write the DateTime column to the CSV is where the problem happens.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your columns with double-quotes?

Comment: It is likely that you have your datatypes defined wrong as @Dance-Henry suggests.  If they don't match you either have to change the datatype in source & or destination or convert/cast from one datatype to another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the flat file connection manager, target column data type should make sense.

[image]